# BigCommerce(Auth POST response) - 302 redirect

Tags: node.js, bigcommerce

trying to get the auth installation to work properly at the moment and while I was reading the BigCommerce docs, anything else other than a status response of 200 is considered a failure.

Debugger Logs:

```
node-bigcommerce:request Starting Request, with options. { path: '/oauth2/token',
  hostname: 'login.bigcommerce.com',
  method: 'POST',
  port: 443,
  headers:
   { 'User-Agent': 'node-bigcommerce/3.0.0',
     'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
     'Content-Length': 394 } } +0ms

node-bigcommerce:request Sending Data: {"client_id":"123456789abcdefghikl","client_secret":"123456789abcdefghikl","redirect_uri":"https://xxxxx.xxxxx.com:8080/auth","grant_type":"authorization_code","code":"<code from query>","scope":"store_v2_customers_login store_v2_customers_read_only store_v2_default store_v2_orders_read_only store_v2_transactions_read_only","context":"stores/<our_store>"} +5ms

node-bigcommerce:request Status Returned: 302 +234ms

node-bigcommerce:request Headers Returned: {"content-type":"text/html; charset=utf-8","transfer-encoding":"chunked","connection":"close","status":"302 Found","cache-control":"no-cache, no-store","strict-transport-security":"max-age=31536000, max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains","pragma":"no-cache","x-xss-protection":"1; mode=block","x-request-id":"123456789abcdefghikl","location":"https://login.bigcommerce.com/login","p3p":"CP=\"ALL DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND COM NAV\"","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","date":"Fri, 02 Mar 2018 23:53:16 GMT","set-cookie":["_bc_login_session=123456789abcdefghikl; path=/; expires=Sat, 03 Mar 2018 00:08:16 -0000; secure; HttpOnly"]} +1ms
  node-bigcommerce:request Request complete +2ms
  node-bigcommerce:request RESOLVED BODY: <html><body>You are being <a href="https://login.bigcommerce.com/login">redirected</a>.</body></html> +0ms
```

Currently using node v9.7.0
Using "node-bigcommerce" which is listed in the BigCommerce Docs.

I had thoughts about BigCommerce not liking the use of port numbers in the callback urls, like my port 8080. But if that's the case, node will error out when I try to use ports 80 or 443.

When I install the draft app in my sandbox store, the progress indicator overlay will go away and BC will render the HTML sent by my AUTH callback url. However, when you refresh the page the app will disappear from the navigation, and I'm sure this is a result of the above problem.

Any ideas on what the problem might be?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, the problem lied in the node-bigcommerce itself.

Since the POST request content-type is x-www-form-urlencoded
the req.write() was passing in dataString which is a stringified json payload from the GET. BigCommerce expects the request to be in the form of a query string, so you have to take the payload and run querystring.stringify() first then req.write().

After that, everything worked nicely.

This is for API version 3, Node 9.7.1, BC 3.0.0